# Increase the width of a navbar input textbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I increase the input length/width of a navbar text input in this example?

http://www.bootply.com/113955

Answer (score 0):

```
#Question_QuestionText {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Replace `300px` with whatever size you want.

Comment: If I hardcode the length, it is not going to change size (resize) in mobile screen right?

Comment: Right! In that case you can use percentages such as 80%; - the value you use will be the percentage of the input's container. In this case that will probably be the <form> element